# Can't have multiple template bindings on one element Angular2+

Tags: arrays, angular, bind, ngfor, angular-components

I have this error saying

> Can't have multiple template bindings on one element ("
>   list-group-item-success" [draggable] *ngFor="let item of
>   [vegetables[0][0]]" which I know what it means.

But I have no idea how to get around this, because what I'm trying to do is display my 2D array and I need to do nested loop. I will have `i` incremental which will loop through outside array to display the items inside. So all them must be binded to `draggable` directive. But that's the thing that I can't use multiple ngFor's.

Here is the code:

```
vegetables = [[
{name: 'Carrot', type: 'vegetable'},
{name: 'Onion', type: 'vegetable'},
{name: 'Potato', type: 'vegetable'},
{name: 'Capsicum', type: 'vegetable'}],
[
  {name: 'Carrotas', type: 'vegetable'},
  {name: 'Onionas', type: 'vegetable'},
  {name: 'Potatoas', type: 'vegetable'},
  {name: 'Capsicumas', type: 'vegetable'}]]

<div class="card-block scroll-list">
                <div class="list-group">
                    <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-action list-group-item-success" [draggable] *ngFor="let item of [vegetables[0][0]]"
                      *ngFor="let items of [item.values]"
                        [dragClass]="'active'" [dragTransitClass]="'active'" [dragData]="item" [dragScope]="item.type" [dragEnabled]="dragEnabled">
                        {{items.name}}
                    </li>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: ``*ngFor="let vegetable of vegetables"`` and ``*ngFor="let items of vegetable"``

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest use ng-container inside the li. You cannot have 2 *ngFor in one HTML element.

Example:

```
<li class="list-group-item list-group-item-action list-group-item-success" [draggable] *ngFor="let item of [vegetables[0][0]]" [dragClass]="'active'" [dragTransitClass]="'active'" [dragData]="item" [dragScope]="item.type" [dragEnabled]="dragEnabled">
    <ng-container *ngFor="let items of [item.values]">
        {{items.name}}
    </ng-container>
</li>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have two `*ngFor` on the same element. Extract the inner one in a separate `div`.

```
<li *ngFor="let item of [vegetables[0][0]]"...
  <div *ngFor="let items of [item.values]" ...
```

Comment: I believe is better use a `ng-container` instead of `div` since he's not defining any extra properties

Comment: @JacopoSciampi, sure that's another way of doing it